# How come the idea of "event listeners" in swift are divided between actions and protocols?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift4

### My problem

as a new programmer currently learning swift. I was wondering why there seems to be an arbitrary divide between how event listeners are implemented.

In some tutorials, it is pointed out that you can simply drag between view elements on story boards and view controllers to create actions (event listeners).

```
@IBAction func clickButtonListener(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print("hello world")
}
```

But in later tutorials, I noticed that certain event listener-like functionality is also implemented in the form of protocols

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {
     func scrollViewDidScroll(...) {
         ...
     }
}
```

### My questions

1. Why are there seemingly 2 methodologies of implementing event listeners?
2. Are actions just wrapped protocol methods (is one built on top of other)?
3. What are the benefits and drawbacks of each?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. The first concept is called [Target-Action](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/Devpedia-CocoaApp/TargetAction.html), and it comes originally from Nextstep. The advantages against listener protocols is, that you only need to implement one method in a class, that you already have. For event listeners in Java on the opposite you need always a separate class or if-else-chains, if your view contains more than one button.

   The second design pattern is called [Delegation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html). It is helpful for UI elements, which need several different callbacks, where the callback methods must not correspond to a rigid signature like action methods, or may have a return value in opposite to action methods.
2. There is no protocol defining action methods. This is not possible, because the name can be chosen freely. In iOS every method matching the required *shape* (see link to Target-Action above) can be an action method.
3. You can implement as many action methods in a single Cocoa class as you like. Action methods are easy to create (like implementing `Runnable` in Java) and very flexible due to the free choice of names.

   Delegates, on the other hand, have more capabilities and allow a more precise specification of callbacks.

**Note (compared to Java):** You can implement event listeners in Java as standalone classes or anonymous (inline) class. Each of these event listener classes can contain exactly one event listener of the same type, so that most of the time the inline variant is chosen to avoid having an unnecessarily large number of classes. The anonymous classes have also the advantage that they can access the properties of the surrounding class.

But if you need many event listeners inside of an action the code get more and more complex and becomes more and more illegible due to the higher indentation levels, especially if the event listeners are nested.

In contrast, the nesting depth on action methods in Cocoa is flat. The class gets longer with more action methods, but the individual methods do not become more complex.

Comment: Are they different or is one built on top of the other?

Comment: No, they're completely independent.

Comment: Is it possible for you to reformat your answer into distinct answers for each separate question 1) 2) 3). I feel as if this would increase clarity and help me and others understand what you are saying better. Or perhaps even provide some short pseudocode examples to illustrate your point. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Protocols are like contracts. When a type conforms to a protocol, the compiler can reason about behavior of the type without knowing at compile time what that type actually will be at run time. For example, the scroll view "knows" at compile time that there might be an instance that wants to know when the scroll view did scroll. So it sends that instance this message.

Target-action is something completely different. With the target-action pattern, you create a connection between to objects. Let's say you have a button in you UI and you drag a connection to the view controller. Then the button has a target and when ever something specific (for example a touch up inside event) happens, the button sends an action to the connected element. You can even ask the button for all the targets that are connected.